# Integer within certain interval.

Tags: analysis, integers

I have to show that there is a unique integer within the interval $[a,b]$ where

$a = -\frac{3}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{9}{4} + 2(n+1)}$

and

$b = -\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + 2(n+1)}$

as well as $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now the uniqueness is easy by showing that there can be one integer within this interval at maximum. This is done by calculating $(b-a)$ and finding that $(b-a)<1$.

But how do I prove that there indeed exists one?

Comment: It might be worth seeing when $a$ and $b$ are integers.  It then becomes easy

Comment: But that won't prove for the cases when a and b are not integers. I think we can break the problem into 2 parts....

Comment: Wait, I think you went wrong somewhere, @Octavius. If you can prove 1=|b-a| for all a and b which are not integers, then there will definitely be an integer between a and b when and b are themselves not integers.

Comment: If the difference between any 2 real numbers a and b is greater than 1, then there will be at least one integer between [a, b].

Comment: yes, but I proved that the difference (b-a) is smaller than 1, i.e. (b-a) < 1.

Comment: yeah! I just proved that too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the contrary - $\nexists$ an integer lying in $[a,b]$. Then, $\exists\  m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $[a,b] \subset [m,m+1]$.

So, 
\begin{align}
m &< a \\
\implies m+\frac{3}{2} &< \sqrt{\frac{9}{4} + 2(n+1)} \\
\implies m^2 + 3m &< 2n+ 2
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
b &< m+1 \\
\implies \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + 2(n+1)} &< m+\frac{3}{2} \\
\implies 2n +2 &< m^2 + 3m + 2 \\
\implies 2n &<
m^2 + 3m\end{align}

Hence, we must have $m(m+3) = 2n+1$. But, $m(m+3)$ is an even number, while $2n+1$ is odd.

This is a contradiction, and so the result is proved.

Comment: An elegant solution, which I accept gratefully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am down to something so I thought I should share it.
It is given (or can be proved) b>a. Let a = m-h, b=m+k, where m is the integer unique integer lying in [a,b] and h and k are real positive numbers. We can (or have already above) prove that h and k are not integers that their sum is less than 1. First let n+1 be k. Reduce a and b to a form of k.
Solving that, we get
(2a+3)^2 = (2b+1)^2 + 8.

It reduces to (a+b+2)(a-b+1) = 2.

Putting in values for a and b,
we get

(2m+h-k+2)(h+k+1) = 2.

This reduces to proving that m is indeed an integer. Hope this can help somehow.

Please tell if any mistakes are there.